# Reorder the wsdl:definitions in an ASP.NET web service

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, wsdl, namespaces

I am creating an ASP.NET web service that implements a specific existing WSDL.  There are a couple minor differences that are probably not a big deal, but I would like to get as close of a match as possible.  I am starting to think this isn't even possible.

This first difference is the wsdl:definitions are in a different order, and have one additional value.

This is what I want it to look like:

```
<wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:tns="urn:MyNamespace:Gateway"
    xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
    targetNamespace="urn:MyNamespace:Gateway"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
>
```

and this is what I am getting:

```
<wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
    xmlns:tns="urn:MyNamespace:Gateway"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
    targetNamespace="urn:MyNamespace:Gateway"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
>
```

Notice that they are in a different order, and I have the additional ***soap12*** namespace.  How do I get them in the same order and remove the soap12 namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://forums.parasoft.com/index.php?showtopic=920 you can switch off the soap12 namespace with the following code in your web.config:

```
<system.web>
 <webServices>
   <protocols>
     <remove name="HttpSoap12"/>
   </protocols>
 </webServices>
</system.web>
```